# Existence of a vector

Tags: vector-analysis

Let us take $V$ a vector field such that $V=(y,x,-2z)$ does there exist $W$ such that $\mathrm{rot}(W)=-2V$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i've tried w=(p(x,y,z),q(x,y,z),0) but it didn't work

Comment: Why didn't it work?

Comment: if there exists such a W then V=-1/2rot(W) which means div(V)=-1/2div(rot(W))=0 which is not in this case cause div(V)=-2 and not 0 so there is no W ,is my reasoning right?

Comment: THERE you go. That's correct. Since $\text{div}(\text{rot}(W)) = 0$ always, there can't be any $W$.

Comment: thanks a lot !!

Comment: You're welcome. In general, try to post things you've tried as part of your questions. And you learned more by figuring it out yourself, by the way, so good for you!!